# how do I invoke my void method in Java?

Tags: java, methods, parameters

this program works.. i tested it without using switch.. my only issue is not knowing how to invoke the whichtable(int number) method.

```
package switchmathtables;  
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class MathTables {
public static void printAddition(int x){
    int i = 1; 
    while (x <= 12){
    System.out.print (0 + x + "   ");
    x = x + 1;
}
System.out.println ("");

}
public static void printSinTable(){
double x, y, z;    
System.out.print("Angle 30 degree ");
    x = 30 * Math.PI/180;
    System.out.println ("sin(" + x + ") is " + Math.asin(x));
     System.out.print("Angle 60 degree ");
    y = 30 * Math.PI/180;  
}
public static void printCosTable(){
double x, y, z;     
System.out.print("Angle 30 degree ");
    x = 30 * Math.PI/180;
    System.out.println ("cos(" + x + ") is " + Math.acos(x));
    System.out.print("Angle 60 degree ");
    y = 30 * Math.PI/180;
}
public static void printTanTable(){
 double x, y, z;  
 System.out.print("Angle 30 degree ");
    x = 30 * Math.PI/180;
    System.out.println("tan(" + x + ") is " + Math.atan(x));
    System.out.print("Angle 60 degree ");
    y = 30 * Math.PI/180;   
}



public static void printCommonLog(){
double x = 0.5;
while(x < 10) {
    System.out.println( x + "  " + Math.log(x) / Math.log(10));
    x = x + 0.05;
}

}
```

this is the void switch method i want to call from my main. I am not sure how too

```
public static void printAddition(){
int x = 1;
while (x <= 12){
    System.out.print (0 + x + "   ");
    x = x + 1;
}
System.out.println ("");
}
public static void whichtable(int number){

switch (number){
 case 1:
     printCommonLog();
     break;
 case 2:
     printAddition();
     break;
 case 3:
     printTanTable();
     break;        
 case 4:
     printCosTable();
     break;
 case 5:
     printSinTable();
     break;
 }
```

This is my main and I want to call the whichtable(int number) method into it..

```
 } 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 int number;
 String inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Type 1 for CommonLog table"
     + "Type 2 for Addition table"
     + "Type 3 for the tangent table"
     + "Type the 4 for the cosine table"
     + "Type the 5 for the sine");       
  }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :

```
whichtable(Integer.parseInt(inputStr));
```

the `whichtable` method expects an `Integer`, so you must convert it.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that they typed in an integer on the input string you could say `MathTables.whichtable(Integer.parseInt(inputStr))` in main and it would print out one of the tables.

If main is in the same class as MathTables then you would only need to use `whichtable(Integer.parseInt(inputStr))`, but it's good programming practice to make a runnable class along with the class you're working with for testing and debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to convert a String to a number from your dialog, you need to parse it.

```
int option = Integer.parseInt(inputStr); // Convert the String to an "int"
whichtable(option); // Call the void method!
```

Answer (score 1):

In your inputStr you have the input of the user. You have to parse that to integer and then call your method. You can use

```
final Integer choice = Integer.parseInt(stringToParse);
whichtable(choice);
```

Answer (score 0):

you get a string with using JOptionPane.showInputDialog 
so when i type 3 inputStr will be "3"

you can parse it to integer and call your method

```
whichtable(String.valueOf(inputStr));
```